# Is there any constant-time solution to get a random key of a huge object?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object with a ton of keys:

```
const myObject = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    ...
}
```

Had I stored a separate list of keys, I could easily get a random one in constant time:

```
const keys = Object.keys(myObject);
const rand = keys[(Math.random() * keys.length)|0];
```

Moreover, [random element from stream](http://blog.geomblog.org/2008/01/happy-birthday-don-knuth.html) allows one to get such key without needing an additional struct:

```
function pickRandomProperty(obj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in obj)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
           result = prop;
    return result;
}
```

But such solution is linear rather than constant time. Given the new ES6 specs, I wonder if there is, now, a way to get a random key in constant time in function of only `myObject`?

Comment: What are your 'randomness' requirements? Is it enough to satisfy the property that over a long run, each key has been chosen more or less with the same frequency?

Comment: convert it to an array?

Comment: @HonzaRemeš yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your choices are still essentially the same as the ones you've mentioned:

1. Get an array of property names (variable-length time) and then randomly index into it (constant time), or
2. Loop (variable time)

There's no fundamentally new thing for this in ES2015 or ES2016 (or ES2017, come to that).